# Push dev assets to git and track them, but don't have them go live to staging/production?

Tags: git, github, gruntjs, dev-to-production

We develop a website locally, which includes all uncompiled dev assets, before concatenating and minifying and pushing to staging for further testing.

The trouble is, the dev assets also get pushed to staging, and we don't want to do that. But, we do want to carry on committing and updating the dev assets to Git because they are shared across our small team.

Is there a way to separate out the dev assets so they don't get served to the staging and eventually production servers, but do still get pushed to our repo?

This seems like it would be a common problem, yet I can't seem to find any information about it anywhere!

Any help is **greatly** appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple "git only" solution AFAIK. That's why most web projects have a builder which compiles the source (dev) files into a production site which you can then "install" or "deploy". So most people don't use Git to update the production. They use git to push the dev files to a test server where they are build and installed. And only the installation files are then moved further to the production server.

This works because you can always recreate any version of the dev files and rebuild the installation files from that. Hence, it's often redundant to keep the installation files in Git, too.

If you want to keep your development model, I suggest to create two Git repos. The first one only contains dev files with the build scripts. The build scripts copy the results into a second Git repo which can be pushed to test/prod servers.